# Two different servers using one database

Tags: database

Is it normal to have 1 database, on a DB server, that is used by a frontend (web) server, but then also have a third server doing an `UPDATE` in that database?

I want the frontend server to send queries to a DB table to check if an action is "done".

```
SELECT status FROM table WHERE id = '...';
```

But that action will only be "done" if this third server sends an `UPDATE` to that table, and updates the status.

```
UPDATE table SET status = 'done' WHERE id is = '...';
```

So 2 different servers (frontend and backend) will need to communicate with the DB.. is that potentially problematic? Is there a 'cleaner' solution?

Comment: No that’s quite common,

Answer (score 0):

It is common to do it. What you need to consider is the isolation level of transactions. 
As long as it is ‘Read Committed’ or above, those simple queries are safe.

For more complex and multiple queries need to be excuted then Repeatable Read or Serializable level should be considered.

Comment: I found this: `Suppose that you are running in the default REPEATABLE READ isolation level. When you issue a consistent read (that is, an ordinary SELECT statement), InnoDB gives your transaction a timepoint according to which your query sees the database. If another transaction deletes a row and commits after your timepoint was assigned, you do not see the row as having been deleted. Inserts and updates are treated similarly.` I think for my purposes REPEATABLE READ is good, because when the select statement still sees the status as "not done", it will just issue another one in a few seconds.